# Can I pass a field of a class to a constructor or a method?

Tags: java, oop, structure

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class Map {
    protected PriorityQueue<Node> openNodes;
}
```

My implementation currently work like this:

```
public Map() {
        PriorityQueue<Node> openNodes = new PriorityQueue<Node>((Node node1, Node node2) -> Integer.compare(node1.getFinalCost(), node2.getFinalCost()));
    }
```

However, I would like to use an implementation like this aswell:

```
public Map() {
        PriorityQueue<Node> openNodes = new PriorityQueue<Node>((Node node1, Node node2) -> Integer.compare(node1.getHeuristicCost(), node2.getHeuristicCost()));
    }
```

Is there any way to pass the *heuristicCost* or the *finalCost* fields of my Node class to the constructor to achieve these different behaviours? Something like this:

```
public Map(*fieldName*) {
        PriorityQueue<Node> openNodes = new PriorityQueue<Node>((Node node1, Node node2) -> Integer.compare(node1.get*fieldName*(), node2.get*fieldName*()));
    }
```

If not, could you suggest a solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a comparator from a method reference, using [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```java
public Map(ToIntFunction<Node> compareBy) {
    this.openNodes = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(compareBy));
}
```

Then you can write `new Map(Node::getFinalCost)` or `new Map(Node::getHeuristicCost)`.